# Issue with removing from array

Tags: arrays, swift2

I'm trying to check whether an object (order of type Order) already exists in an array (newOrderItems - array of Order) before appending it so that I avoid duplicates.

Array declaration:

```
var newOrderItems = [Order]()
```

Attempting to delete if exists before appending:

```
let order = Order(item: item!.name, price: item!.price, quantity: 1, status: "", tags: "", selectedTags: item!.selectedTags, id: item!.id)

if newOrderItems.filter({ $0 == order }).count > 0 {
    newOrderItems.removeAtIndex(newOrderItems.indexOf(order))
}

newOrderItems.append(order!)
```

The above gives 2 errors:

****** Error 1 ******

Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Order' and 'Order?'

in line:

```
if newOrderItems.filter({ $0 == order }).count > 0
```

****** Error 2 ******

Cannot convert value of type 'Order?' to expected argument type '@noescape (Order) throws -> Bool'

in line:

```
newOrderItems.removeAtIndex(newOrderItems.indexOf(order))
```

What am I missing here?

---

****** EDIT ******

I can get it to work if I rewrite it using a loop:

```
var counter = 0

for item in newOrderItems {

    if item.id == order?.id {
        newOrderItems.removeAtIndex(counter)
        break
    }
    counter++
}
newOrderItems.append(order!)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compare the comparison code in your `filter`:

```
if newOrderItems.filter({ $0 == order }).count > 0 { ... }
```

With that in the `while` loop:

```
if item.id == order?.id { ... }
```

Swift doesn't know how to compare 2 objects of type `Order` but it knows how to compare 2 `Ints` (assuming `id` is of type `Int`)

---

### Solution

Define an `==` function for `Order`:

```
func ==(lhs: Order, rhs: Order) -> Bool {
    return lhs.id == rhs.id
}
```

Then you should be able to use `filter`

```
if newOrderItems.filter({ $0 == order }).count > 0 {
    newOrderItems.removeAtIndex(newOrderItems.indexOf(order))
}
```

However, if you want your OrderID to be unique, a `Dictionary` may be more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution to your problem. only replace your

> if newOrderItems.filter({ $0 == order }).count > 0

with

> if newOrderItems.filter({ $0.id == order.id }).count > 0

Thanks ;]